# Android how to perform specific action right after installation?

Tags: java, android, android-install-apk

i'm developing an application that need to do certain operations right after the installation (mainly save some configuration parameters).

I want to know if it is possible, and how to do it.

And also, is possible to start the application immediately after the installation (i need to start a BroadCastReceiver)

Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The user has to start the app manually. Once the app has started you can then sit on a boot broadcast (BOOT_COMPLETED) and start services in the background from then on, but the first time the app starts needs to be instigated manually.